# Python: two different ways to pass arguments to a function

Tags: python, function, dictionary

can someone help me to understand why these two different ways of calling `myfunc` with the same arguments are not the same? Beginner here.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def myfunc(ServiceCode,PaginationConfig):
    print("ServiceCode: " + ServiceCode)
    print("PaginationConfig: " + str(PaginationConfig))

# Method One
iterator = myfunc(ServiceCode='vpc',PaginationConfig={'MaxItems':123,\
    'PageSize':123,'StartingToken':'TEST-TOKEN'}) # This works as expected

# Method Two
operation_parameters = {'ServiceCode':'vpc','PaginationConifg':{'MaxItems':123,\
    'PageSize':123,'StartingToken':'TEST-TOKEN'}}

iterator = myfunc(**operation_parameters) # This results in "TypeError:\
    myfunc() got an unexpected keyword argument 'PaginationConifg'"
```

Comment: Because you wrote `PaginationConifg` instead of `PaginationConfig`.

Comment: They are the same. Check spelling of "PaginationConifg"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working as expected. There is a mistake in spelling. Please, find the working code for the second function with its output:

```py
operation_parameters = {'ServiceCode':'vpc','PaginationConfig':{'MaxItems':123,\
    'PageSize':123,'StartingToken':'TEST-TOKEN'}}

iterator = myfunc(**operation_parameters)
```

**Output**

```sh
ServiceCode: vpc
PaginationConfig: {'MaxItems': 123, 'PageSize': 123, 'StartingToken': 'TEST-TOKEN'}
```